# Query application locks created with sp_getapplock in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have an application where I use "application locks" to prevent two users from stepping on each other in some scenarios.

To acquire application locks, I use sp_getapplock:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql

The @resource parameter receives a string that I generate to identify the document edited.

Acquiring the lock generates an entry in the query sys.dm_tran_locks.

I would like to search the view sys.dm_tran_locks after a lock fails -- to retrieve the additional information of the process that has the lock (for example, joining with some other views I can get the user login and host of the process that currently owns a lock).

This view sys.dm_tran_locks includes a column called 'resource_description'. However, there is some weird behavior in it, showing the resource name decorated with gibberish.

Examples:

- @resource parameter is 'W_1058', column shows
  '0:[W_1058]:(4687ad63)'.
- @resource parameter is 'W_1042', column shows
  '0:[W_1042]:(a908fe21)'.

Notice how my original @resource value is embedded within this column.

There is also the procedure applock_test. This checks whether a lock is already acquired, however this returns only 0 or 1 and no information that is useful to find the user login and host that have the lock.

Is there any way to retrieve the resource name only, without the gibberish? Or, can I assume the structure of this 'resource_description' will be always the same and truncate the pieces before and after the right parentheses?

Comment: Personally, I'd try to obtain the lock with a long time out value and monitor for blocking. Once you have blocking, you can identify the blocker rather easily through sys.dm_os_waiting_task or similar.